# Handling Firebase errors in python admin sdk

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication

What is the correct way to handle this error? I've created two stack questions and both answers no longer work. Here is my code:

```
from firebase_admin import auth as admin_auth

try:
    uid = 'testUID'
    email = 'test@test.com' # test@test.com already exists
    admin_auth.update_user(uid, email=email)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I get the following response:

```
Failed to update user: testUID. Server response: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "invalid", "message": "EMAIL_EXISTS" } ], "code": 400, "message": "EMAIL_EXISTS" } }
```

Am I creating the exception correctly? If I use:

```
except ValueError as e:
```

I get the response in a string. What I want is to get the status/code and message.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Nope Just created special errors. Could never parse the response

Answer (score 0):

The Admin SDK throws 2 potential exceptions in the Auth methods:

- ValueError if the arguments are malformed (pretty much what you would expect ValueError to be used for)
- firebaseadmin.auth.AuthError if there was an *upstream* failure, meaning something went wrong in firebase or the user couldn't be found, created etc.

The latter can be inspected at by looking at the properties of the exception.

```
try:
    auth.get_user(uid)
except auth.AuthError as exc:
    print(exc.code)
```

Obviously, ValueError does not have exc.code.

Answer (score 0):

import exceptions from the firebse_admin

```
try:
auth.get_user(uid)
except exceptions.FirebaseErrorr as exc:
print(exc.code)
except ValueError as e :
    print(e)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).